# Reverse Proxy which allows connection limiting?

Tags: reverse-proxy

I'm looking for a reverse proxy which has a special feature: it must support configuring the maximum number of connections (to 1). The reason is that I have a legacy application which gets stuck if a normal browser opens more than one connection to it.

I know that I can configure the browser to not use more than one connection, but that's not a permanent solution. I would prefer a lightweight solution since this is running on a 500MHz MIPS router, so I've looked into **tinyproxy**, but it doesn't seem to be able to limit the number of outgoing connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Squid - look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-squid-proxy-number-web-connections.html

Unfortunately the problem is probably harder then you suspect, as each image (or css file) on the page might want a separate connection, so limiting to a single connection might not work - or might just slow things down.

Another solution might be to just use iptables to do your connection limiting - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-connection-limits-howto/  which would probably be a lighter weight solution then running a proxy.